# linq to XML (C# to VB.net conversion)

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

What is equivalent of below in VB.net

```
      var list = (from x in xd.Descendants("product").Attributes("title") select 
      new { Title= x.Value}).ToList();
```

VB.net 
          Dim list = (From x In xd.Descendants("product").Attributes("title") _ 
                     Select New (   ???    )).ToList()

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
New With { .Title = x.Value }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want a List(Of )?  If your anonymous type only has a single property, wouldn't it be easier to work with a result that was a List(Of String)?

Here's the full vb.net syntax for your query along with some XML to test it with.  I generally separate out the .ToList call, but that's mainly for clarity.  Also note, that with the code below, the query is not executed until the .ToList call, so it may be helpful to separate them for that reason as well.

After running this code, ListA is type `List(Of <anonymous type>)` and ListB is type `List(Of String)`

```
Dim testXml = <test>
                  <product title="Prod1"/>
                  <product title="Prod2"/>
                  <product title="Prod3"/>
              </test>

Dim queryA = From t In testXml...<product> _
             Select New With {.Title = t.@title}

Dim listA = queryA.ToList

Dim queryB = From t In testXml...<product> _
             Select t.@title

Dim ListB = queryB.ToList
```